# How to get user's GPS coordinates by clicking a button?

Tags: android, gps, android-maps

Hello there i'm having a problem here

i have an add and edit form for my point of views databases
it has two EditText for the coordinates, for Longitude and Latitude
and it has a button to get the current coordinates
if i click the button, the two EditTexts filled with the coordinates
and the user can proceed to insert or edit the data

my code returning a java.nullPointerException, i don't know why...

this is my code :

```
btn_getkoor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{

                    LocationListener gpsLocation = new MyLocationListener();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, gpsLocation); //new MyLocationListener());
                    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                    final TextView error_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_text);

                    if (location != null) {

                        EditText et_longitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_longitude);
                        EditText et_latitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_latitude);

                        et_longitude.setText(""+location.getLongitude());   // longitude textview
                        et_latitude.setText(""+location.getLatitude());     //latitude textview

                        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) location);
                        locationManager = null;

                    }else{
                        toastkeun("Terjadi Kesalahan dalam pengambilan koordinat");             //toast function
                        error_text.setText("Terjadi Kesalahan dalam pengambilan koordinat");    //textview for showing errors
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    toastkeun(e.toString());
                }

            }
        });
```

Any solution?

I'm already set the Manifest file FYI

Comment: where you initiate locationManager?

Comment: protected LocationManager locationManager;

i place it before onCreate()

Comment: also on which line does this NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to say from your code, though :

If you haven't done this, here is the code :

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: where i should place that line?

Comment: ok i get my coordinates now, but it returning java.lang.ClassCastException : android location.Location

Comment: First you MUST always tell what is the line causing the exception. Second `locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) location)` location cannot be cast into LocationListener. They are different classes!

Comment: so how to stop updating the coordinates?

Comment: Using `removeUpdates(gpsLocation);`

Answer (score 0):

```
     LocationManager locationManager;
    String bestProvider;
    String LOCATION_SERVICE="location" ; 
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        //criteria.setAccuracy();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);  // More accurate, GPS fix.
        bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);
    location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
if (location != null) {

                        EditText et_longitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_longitude);
                        EditText et_latitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_latitude);

                        et_longitude.setText(""+location.getLongitude());   // longitude textview
                        et_latitude.setText(""+location.getLatitude());     //latitude textview

                       // locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) location);
                        locationManager = null;

                    }else{
                        toastkeun("Terjadi Kesalahan dalam pengambilan koordinat");             //toast function
                        error_text.setText("Terjadi Kesalahan dalam pengambilan koordinat");    //textview for showing errors
                    }
```

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong :  `locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) location)`